# I found a base64 decoder written in C. It works correctly when I compile it with GCC. But it went wrong with cl.exe. Why?

Tags: c, gcc, cl

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 **/

#include "base64.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 // base64 tables
static const char basis_64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
static const signed char index_64[128] = {
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
    -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 62,
    -1, -1, -1, 63, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
    1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,
    39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
#define CHAR64(c) (((c) < 0 || (c) > 127) ? -1 : index_64[(c)])

// base64_encode    :    base64 encode
//
// value            :    data to encode
// vlen             :    length of data
// (result)         :    new char[] - c-str of result
char* base64_encode(const unsigned char* value, size_t vlen) {
    char* result = (char*)malloc((vlen * 4) / 3 + 5);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    char* out = result;
    while (vlen >= 3) {
        *out++ = basis_64[value[0] >> 2];
        *out++ = basis_64[((value[0] << 4) & 0x30) | (value[1] >> 4)];
        *out++ = basis_64[((value[1] << 2) & 0x3C) | (value[2] >> 6)];
        *out++ = basis_64[value[2] & 0x3F];
        value += 3;
        vlen -= 3;
    }
    if (vlen > 0) {
        *out++ = basis_64[value[0] >> 2];
        unsigned char oval = (value[0] << 4) & 0x30;
        if (vlen > 1)
            oval |= value[1] >> 4;
        *out++ = basis_64[oval];
        *out++ = (vlen < 2) ? '=' : basis_64[(value[1] << 2) & 0x3C];
        *out++ = '=';
    }
    *out = '\0';

    return result;
}

// base64_decode    :    base64 decode
//
// value            :    c-str to decode
// rlen             :    length of decoded result
// (result)         :    new unsigned char[] - decoded result
unsigned char* base64_decode(const char* value, size_t* rlen) {
    *rlen = 0;
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;

    size_t vlen = strlen(value);
    unsigned char* result = (unsigned char*)malloc((vlen * 3) / 4 + 1);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned char* out = result;

    while (1) {
        if (value[0] == 0) {
            //*out = '\0';
            return result;
        }
        c1 = value[0];
        if (CHAR64(c1) == -1) {
            goto base64_decode_error;
            ;
        }
        c2 = value[1];
        if (CHAR64(c2) == -1) {
            goto base64_decode_error;
            ;
        }
        c3 = value[2];
        if ((c3 != '=') && (CHAR64(c3) == -1)) {
            goto base64_decode_error;
            ;
        }
        c4 = value[3];
        if ((c4 != '=') && (CHAR64(c4) == -1)) {
            goto base64_decode_error;
            ;
        }

        value += 4;
        *out++ = (CHAR64(c1) << 2) | (CHAR64(c2) >> 4);
        *rlen += 1;

        if (c3 != '=') {
            *out++ = ((CHAR64(c2) << 4) & 0xf0) | (CHAR64(c3) >> 2);
            *rlen += 1;

            if (c4 != '=') {
                *out++ = ((CHAR64(c3) << 6) & 0xc0) | CHAR64(c4);
                *rlen += 1;
            }
        }
    }

base64_decode_error:
    *result = 0;
    *rlen = 0;

    return result;
}
// Below is my test.
int main() {
    char str[] = "123456";
    char* encoded = base64_encode(str, strlen(str));
    printf("encode : %s\n", encoded);
    int rlen = 3;
    char* decoded = base64_decode(encoded, &rlen);
    printf("decode : %s\n", decoded);
    printf("len: %d\n", strlen(decoded));
    return 0;
}
```

Result (cl.exe) :
encode : MTIzNDU2
decode : 123456?
len: 7

Then I thought these code may work in unix, and the compiler may be cc(gcc).
So I compiled these code in my WSL with gcc, and it worked correctly.

Result (gcc) :
encode : MTIzNDU2
decode : 123456
len: 6

Why gcc is correct but cl is not?

What's the difference between these two compiler in this case?

Comment: Your compiler warnings should have pointed out at least one way in which your test code is broken. (If you're compiling with warnings off, turn them on.)

Comment: Perhaps `base64.h` uses the `long` type expecting it to have 64 bits. With MSVC it is 32 bits.

Comment: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: As pointed out by the answer below this is a case of incorrect expectations (sometimes known as RTFM). You expected `base64_decode` to return a null terminated string, but it does not. So the code you found is not bugged, the code you wrote might have worked in different circumstances, but in this case it's a bugged program.

Comment: Also worth saying that base64 is often used to encode binary data, so there is no particular reason to expect the output of a base64 decoding routine to be null terminated.

Comment: Replace your *malloc* by *calloc*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason that `base64_decode` returns a length to you.  If (but only if) you know that the encoded text had been human-readable, you could print it back out like this:

```
int rlen;
char* decoded = base64_decode(encoded, &rlen);
printf("decode : %.*s\n", rlen, decoded);
printf("len: %d\n", rlen);
```

`%.*s` tells printf that the length of the string you're printing is given, not by the usual `\0` terminator in the string, but rather, by an explicit length you pass in.

As mentioned in the comments, Base-64 encoding is usually used to encode arbitrary binary data, which might contain embedded `\0` characters, and which typically isn't null-terminated.  For arbitrary binary data, you usually want to carry the length around as a separate variable, like `rlen` here.

Another issue is that this `base64_decode` function is returning the length as a `size_t` value, not `int`.  So you really need:

```
size_t rlen;
char* decoded = base64_decode(encoded, &rlen);
printf("decode : %.*s\n", (int)rlen, decoded);
printf("len: %zd\n", rlen);
```

Comment: Yes. My thought was wrong. `base64_decode()` change `rlen` . That means I should use it when producing decoded data. For example, base64 usually be used to encode image. When I decode a image, I don't want a `\0` at the end. I should use `rlen` to get the edge of data.

Answer (score 6):

Both compilers are correct. The shown code results in undefined behavior. `base64_decode()` fails to return a `'\0'`-terminated string, so both using the returned `char` pointer with `printf` and `strlen` results in undefined behavior.